# SQLyog (webyog) change table access for root

Tags: sqlyog

We are more than 1 user working on SQLyog (webyog), we all use root to login, recently it has been brought to my attention that some confidential data has been leaked from 1 of the tables that I work on.  I have been instructed to have a look into this.  Can I protect this table with a new user account from root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change the root password immediately.**

Your employer is liable for a couple incidents given your scenario.

If confidential info of any kind is being stored on that server, only the people with proper training and classification should have access to said information.

You should create a new user for EACH employee (or for each employee type [e.g: 'root', 'accounting', 'library', 'developer']) and give permissions accordingly.

The only user with global access should be root, and possibly whatever developer account you may create.

Everyone else should have access only to the tables they need and only have access to basic CRUD (Create, Update, Delete) functions. Your accountant may know basic SELECTing statements, but he shouldn't be DROPping tables.